# Find the probability that at least one of two light bulb survives for 920 hours.

Tags: probability, self-learning

> The length in hours $X$ of lightbulb A is $N(800,14400)$ and $Y$ (lightbulb B) is $N(850,2500)$. Find the probability that at least one of the bulbs lives for at least 920 hours.

Would this be:

$$(1 - P(X < 920)) * (1 - P(Y < 920))$$

Comment: It looks correct!

Comment: Not quite. The probability that they are both dead is $\Pr(X\lt a)\Pr(Y\lt a)$. Subtract this from $1$.  What you calculated was the probability they are **both** alive.

Comment: You need to do this: 1-(Prob. of both dead), which you can easily do using the hint provided by Andre!